# Full screen background, white space below footer when window is small

Tags: html, css, fullscreen

***Solution: I used http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/ and it is the best solution I found. Not perfect since the background graphic doesn't "scroll" downwards but still works.***

Here is a screenshot of my problem:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, when I resize the window (make it smaller) white spaces will appear. Does anyone have a clue what the problem is?

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <header>
        <div id="services">
            <div class="column-left">Column left</div>
            <div class="column-center">Column center</div>
            <div class="column-right">Column right</div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section><img src="http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/batman-logo-big.gif" alt="PPP" /></section>

    <footer>
            <p>Some text here</p>
    </footer>
</div>            
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
    body {padding:0;margin:0;}
html {
    color: #fff;
}
#wrapper {
    background: url(../images/bg2.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

}
#services {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.column-left{ 
    float: left;
    margin-top: 100px; 
    width: 200px; 
}
.column-right{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 100px; 
    width: 200px; 
}
.column-center{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 100px; 
    width: 200px; 
}

footer { 
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-color: white;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 800px;
}
section {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    width: 800px;
}
section img {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: You can see the problem in this jsfiddle made by 3rror404: http://jsfiddle.net/aju126yw/2/   Play around with the preview window size and you will see that white space form below the footer and on the right side. It seems to me that the logo is causing some trouble?

Answer (score 0):

> Pretty good solution I thought, even if it isn't technically
>   resizeable, since **you can't set the size of a CSS background-image**.

[Found on cssTricks](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/)

Maybe this is an option for you, but this is a solution with jquery:

```
<head>
    ....
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("img.source-image").hide();
        var $source = $("img.source-image").attr("src");
        $('#page-body').css({
            'backgroundImage': 'url(' + $source +')',
            'backgroundRepeat': 'no-repeat',
            'backgroundPosition': 'top center'
        });
    }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body id="page-body">
    <img class="source-image" src="images/image.jpg" alt="" />
</body>
```

[Found on cssTricks](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/)

Comment: Any html/css only fixes?